# How to use LSTMs for predicting the value for a specific hour within a day, given past daily data?

Tags: time-series, lstm

I think the heading tells everything. Let's say you have the stock price.

So you have for every day the price at every hour.

No I want to predict the next hour given all prevoius hours at a new day. I don't know how to choose an architecture and even how to train such case when you have data for past days. My problem is also (if it is a problem?!) the different kind of times : hours vs days.

So, I think you have to train a lstm for a day with time step of 1 hour to predict the next hour. But how to incoporate all other days in training?

Comment: Do you only have one historical price per stock per day? Do you mean "given past hourly data" instead?

Comment: No, it is hourly per day, but this is arbitrary you can have any fine grained time step within day.

Comment: @ Imran: Any suggestions?